# where am I storing a value when I declare a property of a function?

Tags: javascript, properties

I don't understand what's going on here. If I do this:

```
function foo() {
  return 'hey there';
}
foo.value = 'some random value';

console.log(foo.value) // 'some random value';
console.log(typeof foo) // 'function'
console.log(foo) // ƒ foot()...
```

I can access later `foo.value` without problem but if I do `typeof foo` it returns `function`.

Where is `foo.value` being stored. Is definitely not in the global object. Can a function store properties then?

Comment: Yes, every function is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects, and they can have properties on them. Some properties already exist without you doing anything. For example, you can do the following:

```js
function test() {}

console.log(test.name);
```

so when you do:

```
foo.value = 'some random value';
```

you're just adding an additional property on that object.

Comment: and why does typeof returns 'function' instead of 'object'? Does it looks at the constructor or something like that?

Comment: That's just how the typeof operator is specified to work: function objects return the string 'function', nulls and other objects return 'object'. I doubt its looking at the constructor, though i don't know the details of how it is implemented.

Comment: @oquiroz If it's an object and not callable you get `object`, if it's an object and callable you get `function`.

Comment: @oquiroz when speaking of types in OO, we tend to speak of the most specific type, knowing that there's a lineage of more abstract types related to it.  So an Apple is a kind of Fruit, and you have an apple in your hand, its type is Apple (which is a kind of Fruit, which is a kind of Object)

Answer (score 0):

> Can a function store properties then?

Yes. A function is an object of type `function` and as with all objects you can assign properties to it.

This behaviour can be used to model static properties and methods on functions/classes.

```
function Foo() {
    this.value = 'instance';
}

Foo.value = 'static';
console.log(Foo.value);
console.log(new Foo().value);
```